# Did I solve this question about a line intersecting a plane correctly?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, vectors

I'm asked to find if there is any point of intersection, and if so, where it is between the line represented by the symmetric equation $\frac{x-3}{3}=\frac{y+1}{-2}=\frac{z-10}{4}$ and the plane represented by the vector equation $[x, y,z]=[-6, 3, 6]+s[1, 2, 3]+t[2, -1, 2]$.

I found that there is a point of intersection, and that it is at $(\frac{102}{7}, -\frac{61}{7}, \frac{178}{7})$. I found that point to be a bit messy, which the answers to these assignment questions usually aren't. So I'm wondering if I got the answer right or not.

EDIT:
Here is how I got the answer, to clear up the confusion about what I'm asking:

First, I made parametric equations for the line:

> $x=3+3t$
>
> $y=-1-2t$
>
> $z=10+4t$

Then, I made a scalar equation for the plane.

> Normal vector: $[1,2,3]×[2,-1,2]=[7,4,-5]$
>
> Current Equation: $7x+4y-5z+D=0$
>
> Using point on plane $(-6, 3, 6)$: $7(-6)+4(3)-5(5)+D=0\implies D=60$
>
> Final Equation: $7x+4y-5z+60=0$

Then I substituted the parametric equations into the plane equations to find the value of $t$:

> $7(3+3t)+4(-1-2t)-5(10+4t)+60=0 \implies t=\frac{27}{7}$

Then I substituted the value for $t$ into the parametric equations:

> $x=3+3(\frac{27}{7})\implies x=\frac{102}{7}$
>
> $y=-1-2(\frac{27}{7})\implies y=-\frac{61}{7}$
>
> $z=10+4(\frac{27}{7})\implies z=\frac{178}{7}$

Which thus leaves ut at the conclusion I drew that the line intersects the plane at $(\frac{102}{7}, -\frac{61}{7}, \frac{178}{7})$.

Comment: Well, does the point satisfy both equations (for some $s$, $t$ for the plane)? (If you explain how you obtained that point, we can tell you if the procedure was correct.)

Comment: Well, I'm not really unsure about the procedure, I'm more unsure about the result. That's why I intentionally left the procedure out.

Comment: That's the way I would do it. You have a typo in your "Using point on plane line". But the equation for the plane is correct, assuming you computed the cross product giving the Normal vector correctly (I didn't check that). Everything else is ok.

Comment: I tried using WolframAlpha, it gets the same result as me. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=[1%2C2%2C3]%C3%97[2%2C%E2%88%921%2C2]&dataset=

So, you verified that the value I found for $t$ were right? And that there's nothing wrong about my approach?

Comment: It's perfectly correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) the vecto parallel of the line is $u=(3,-2,4)$ and the vector perpendicular to the plane is $n=(1,2,3)×(2,-1,2)$. If $u.n \ne 0$, there is an intersection point. If it is zero check if the line lies on the plane by one point substitution namely $(3,-1,10)$

(2) To get the intersection points use the parametric equation of the line $r=(3,-1,10)+t(3,-2,4)$ i.e. $x=3+3t,...$ in the cartesian equation of the plane$[(x+6,y-3,z-6).n=0]$ and find the value of $t$.
I hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not really wondering about HOW to do it, I'm wondering if I arrived at the right answer.